# How do I enable case-insensitive autocompletion on Xonsh?

Tags: command-line, xonsh

I'm running the [Xonsh](http://xon.sh) shell, and I would like to emulate case-insensitive tab completion a la `zsh`.

As an example, typing `~/Downl<TAB>` and `~/downl<TAB>` should both autocomplete to `~/Downloads`.

Is there any way I can enable this in my terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of xonsh v0.6.2, you should set the `$CASE_SENSITIVE_COMPLETIONS` environment variable in the `~/.xonshrc` file. For example:

```
$CASE_SENSITIVE_COMPLETIONS = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and fortunately it's very simple.

In your `~/.config/xonsh/config.json`, simply edit your `env` object to contain:

```
"CASE_SENSITIVE_COMPLETIONS": false
```

As an example:

```json
{
 "env": {
  "AUTO_CD": true,
  "CASE_SENSITIVE_COMPLETIONS": false,
  "SOME_OTHER_ENV": true
 },
 "foreign_shells": [
  ...
 ],
 "xontribs": [
  ...
 ]
}
```

Reload the shell, and you'll have tab completion that completely ignores case.

Comment: The config.json file was removed in xonsh v0.6.2.  Please use the xonshrc file from now on.